# How do I convert an int to time on CSV import in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to convert a large CSV file on import for integer values to a time format? It is currently displaying time as an integer of 5 digits `83210` which I want to be displaying as 8:32:10 or 6 digits `172847`representing 5:28:47.

I want the time to be displayed in the HH:MM:SS format by converting from int which it is currently in to time format.

Comment: You really do want 172847 to display as `'17:28:47'`.  You don't want to lost the hour precision.

Answer (score 1):

Try convert function of mysql.

SELECT CONVERT("83210 ", TIME);

Comment: You are showing the conversion of a *string* not an *integer*.